# Magento2: change the icon in my custom module

Tags: magento2

I need to change the icon in my custom module, I did all steps but nothing change?

**Menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
        <menu>
          <add id="Abir_Conversation::greetings" title="Conversation" translate="title" module="Abir_Conversation" sortOrder="3" dependsOnModule="Abir_Conversation" action="conversation/helloworld" resource="Abir_Conversation::greetings"/>
        </menu>
    </config>
```

**default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <head>
       <css src="Abir_Conversation::css/styles.css"/>
  </head>
</page>
```

**styles.css**

```
       @font-face {
    font-family:'Abir';
    src:url('../fonts/Abir.eot');
    src:url('../fonts/Abir.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('../fonts/Abir.woff') format('woff'),url('../fonts/Abir.ttf') format('truetype'),url('../fonts/Abir.svg') format('svg');font-weight:normal;font-style:normal
} 


      .admin__menu .level-0.item-greetings > a::before {
         content: '\e9d9';
         font-size: 3.0rem;
         padding-top: 0.1rem;
         font-family:'Abir';
         }
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to change the icons of the menu items?

Comment: yes! but nothing change, and there are no errors in my code

Comment: just remove .level-0 from your css selector

Comment: did you solve your problem

Comment: no , the same thing ! i didn't resolved it :(

Comment: Please check edit2

Comment: i checked it, it's \e9d9

Comment: i try with another icon but still the same thing i don't know why! :( thank you vivek for sharing me your time

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change selector of your css just remove `.level-0` from your css selector, it should work.

**EDIT** : Try changing css to following ;

```
.admin__menu .item-greetings > a::before  {
  font-family:'Abir' !important;
  font-style: normal !important;
  font-weight: normal !important;
  font-variant: normal !important;
  text-transform: none !important;
  speak: none;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  content: "\61" !important;
}
```

**EDIT 2 :**

While generating font from svg, you have to define which unicode character will be replaced from your icon, please export your font again and use that code in content, you get your required icon.

Comment: i change it  ` .admin__menu .item-greetings > a::before {
    content: '\e9d9';
    font-size: 3.0rem;
    padding-top: 0.1rem;
    font-family:'Abir';
} `     but nothing changed :/

Comment: check the edit above

Comment: the icon changed to a letter 'a'

Comment: Try changing back to  content: '\e9d9';

Answer (score 0):

I know this is really old but I managed to get a custom icon i created in icomoon into my module admin menu.

I put my fonts in `app/code/vendor/module/view/adminhtml/web/fonts`

In `app/code/vendor/module/view/adminhtml/web/fonts/css/source/_module.less` I put in the following code (changed to match the OP's file)

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'Abir';
    src:  url('../Abir_Conversation/fonts/Abir.eot');
    src:  url('../Abir_Conversation/fonts/Abir.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../Abir_Conversation/fonts/Abir.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../Abir_Conversation/fonts/Abir.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../Abir_Conversation/fonts/Abir.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: block;
}

.admin__menu .level-0.item-greetings > a::before {
    font-family: 'Abir';
    content: '\e9d9';
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

All the articles I read never said how to correctly set the path to the font,